# nullable boolean how to display different results in view based on value

Tags: c#, html, null, boolean, return-value

Say I have the model property `bool? IsCool`

so I may want to display '**Y**' if `true` and '**N**' if `false`

```
<span>@Model.IsCool == true ? Y : N</span>
```

I think that should work.

However how could you get it to work if you wanted a third `option of '-'` displayed if the value is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@(!Model.IsCool.HasValue ? "-" : Model.IsCool.Value ? "Y" : "N")
```

HasValue is simply private boolean property of Nullable type. It sets to true when Nullable has a value. 
And Value just a property of the T type, for "bool?" it will be "bool":

```
    public T Value {
        get {
            if (!HasValue) { 
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_NoValue);
            } 
            return value; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...what are these properties `HasValue` and `Value` on a nullable boolean?

Comment: please elaborate more so the OP can understand more easily where he is missing

Comment: +1 for something I've never known.  I've always checked for null and cast as the non-nullable.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<span>@(!Model.IsCool.HasValue ? '-' : (Model.IsCool.Value ? 'Y' : 'N')</span>
```

It first checks for null. If it is null then displays -

But if it is not null then it goes for second ternary oeprator and displays Y or N according to its value.

Comment: I think your razor syntax is messed up, and you are not accounting for the fact that the bool is nullable.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: How is it now?

Comment: Well your quotes are depicting chars instead of strings, but I guess that's not a big deal, but I'm pretty sure you need to cast `Model.IsCool` as a `bool` (from a `Nullable<bool>`) to do logic comparisons... unless there's some special case for nullable booleans.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: No need to cast when you can use Nullable<bool>.Value

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>
    @(Model.IsCool == null ? "-" : ((bool)Model.IsCool) ? "Y" : "N")
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to check, if the property has any value, and then use it

```
@(Model.IsCool.HasValue ? (Model.IsCool.Value ? "Y" : "N") : "-" ))
```